# I forgot a password windows 10

Tags: windows-10, passwords, user-accounts

I forgot a password administrator account windows 10 but I can access to the other local accounts is there a way to restore or reset her from one of these local accounts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### A) Local Option

If one of those local accounts has administrative rights, you can use that account to reset the Administrator password.

Press Win+X, in the menu that pops up choose "Computer Management". Go to the users and right-click on the Administrator to change the password.

[image]

### B) Online Option

If you are signed in with a Microsoft Account, you can also try to log in as Administrator and enter a wrong password. It will give you then the option "Forgot my Password" and you will be able to reset it with the help of your Microsoft Account. This requires to have been logged in previously with that Account and an Internet Connection, obviously.